# gsm900 module half duplex communication, serie , uart , Embedded system

Tags: c++, embedded, uart, gsm

I developed a program which sends in the first time a single msg a single time a msg which contains "please go" and waits until this person answers it with a msg either the letter B or the letter P is from the say a second time "bravo" and if this person sent B and to say it already send if sent p if did not answer does nothing but be careful the most important thing is that he waits very well until until he receives a msg
but it didn't work i don't know what the problem is:

```
`  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

char incoming_char = 0;
bool waitForResponse = false;

void setup() {
 SIM900.begin(19200);
 Serial.begin(19200);
 delay(1000);
 SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
 delay(100);
 SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
 delay(100);
 sendSMS("please allez");
 waitForResponse = true;
}

void loop() {
 if (waitForResponse && SIM900.available() > 0) {
     incoming_char = SIM900.read();
     Serial.print(incoming_char);

  if (incoming_char == 'b') {  // Assuming 'b' is the first character of "bravo"
     waitForResponse = false;
     sendSMS("bravo");
     } else if (incoming_char == 'p') {  // Assuming 'p' is the first character of "please"
     waitForResponse = false;
     sendSMS("already sent");
    }
  }
 }

void sendSMS(const char *message) {
SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
delay(100);
SIM900.println("AT+CMGS=\"+212684174580\"");
delay(100);
SIM900.println(message);
delay(100);
SIM900.println((char)26);
delay(100);
SIM900.println();
delay(5000);
}`
```

send me sms and waiting that im reponding and send again an sms depend of me answer

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? You need to describe the problem more clearly.

Comment: @paddy   the problem is my gsm code when it sends the first message "please go" it does not wait until it receives another msg and compare is it the letter B or P it immediately start sending "bravo" non stop

Comment: It looks like you are debugging received characters out to the serial port. So, what output do you see there? The only way that you'll output `bravo` is if you receive the character `'b'`. The module should be sending back responses to your AT commands, and I suspect that one of these contains that character. You may need to make a better wrapper around issuing AT commands such that you parse the result, because right now you just ignore everything. That's especially important since some commands can actually report an error along with an arbitrary message.

Comment: @paddy i didn't understand what do you mean , please

Comment: You need to re-read what I wrote then. I am saying that when you send these `AT` commands to the GSM module, it should be sending back responses that give you a result for each command. You are ignoring these. Instead, you just assume that every byte received from SIM900 is an actual SMS, which is almost certainly not true. `Serial.print(incoming_char);` outputs every character that you receive from the SIM900 connection. If _any_ of those characters the letter `b`, it will trigger your "bravo" response.

Comment: You don't need to start over. You simply need to actually debug what you have and investigate what you're receiving back when you issue a command. You can then wrap the command + response handling in a function, and modify your program slightly to call that function.

Comment: @paddy  what do you think right now:                                                                                
 
void loop() {
  if (SIM900.available() > 0) {
    incoming_char = SIM900.read();
    Serial.print(incoming_char);
  }
  delay(1000);
  delay(1000);
  if(incoming_char==5){
    sendSMS("bravo");
  }
  else if (incoming_char==6){
    sendSMS("pas mal");
  }
  else{
    sendSMS("erreur");
  }  
}

Comment: @paddy i just changed the loop function

Comment: What do I think? Well, I think it makes no sense at all, you completely ignored everything I said, and I wasted my time. Good luck with your project, and happy coding!

Comment: @paddy you did not understand what I did, I changed the loop char so that there is no confusion between the commands for sending sms and the comparison command and to tell you that this times worked well but just GSM needs time to get a msg for "AT+CNMI" just to tell you a very important part of coding is to listen to other person's opinion don't act like you're a learned and Good luck

Comment: I am _very_ experienced and you were seeking advice. Your "solution" is a massive hack. You are ignoring the character buffer completely. You might even lose data this way by introducing the sleep in your main loop, depending on how large the internal receive buffer is. AT commands all return responses, and you're treating them as if the only bytes you will receive is when a SMS arrives. That's not true. You need to store responses into your own string buffer and then process that accordingly, or use a finite state machine. There's a huge difference between "seems to work" and "correct".

Comment: @paddy yes yess you are completly right

Comment: i stored my (coming char in a buffer ) and also i noticed that when i receive an char and i converted char to int , every time the msg end by "1310" which is SP in ascii and im thinking now to make it as a condition if SP is here so gsm must send an sms because the problem : is gsm don't wait tell it receive the all msg

Comment: @paddy and im very sorry to didnt listen to your advice because im very stressed

Comment: By "1310" I think you mean CRLF (carriage return followed by linefeed) which is a Windows-style line break. If each command response is terminated by a newline, a very simple approach is to increment a counter every time you issue a command, and then in your loop you can just discard any received character when your count is non-zero, plus also decrement the counter if the received character is a newline. In a pinch, you can ignore the CR and act only the LF, _a.k.a._ `'\n'`. That gets you back to ground zero without doing timing hacks, which are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @paddy , hahaha please don't get mad look what i did : void loop() {
  if (SIM900.available() > 0) {
    incoming_char = SIM900.read();
    Serial.print(incoming_char);
    if(index<5-1){
    buffer[index]=incoming_char;
    index++;
    buffer[index]='\0';
   
  }
  }
  delay(100);
  if (strcmp(buffer, "p") == 0) {
  sendSMS("heyhey");
}  
}

Comment: this time the gsm wait for receiving msg and it didn't do anything if it receives an other charactere not "p" but despite receiving "p" ,the gsm didn't send "heyhey" as a msg                                                                                                                        the initialisation :     char buffer[5];
char incoming_char = 'r';
int index = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identified through discussions in comments, the main issue seems to be poor handling of asynchronous responses from the GSM module. As a result, you are either discarding input or assuming that responses to your *AT* commands are actually SMS and thereby taking inappropriate action.

### Buffering

While there are many valid strategies for dealing with this, one of the most natural ways is to buffer the input and deliver it to a handler function when it's complete. As you have indicated, a complete response ends with a newline or CRLF sequence. So you can simply collect input in your `loop()` until you encounter this.

Here is an easy way to buffer your input, delivering whole lines to a handler function:

```
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE 1000

// This will receive a full message, called when process_input() receives
// a whole line of text.
void handle_message(const char* message, int length, bool overflow)
{
}

// Process any characters in the input buffer. This will deliver a line of text
// to handle_message(). Lines are delimited by CRLF or LF. The string is NUL-
// terminated and excludes the line delimiter.
void process_input()
{
    static char buffer[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
    static int end = 0;
    
    while (SIM900.available() > 0) {
        char c = SIM900.read();
        if (c == '\n') {
            // Check for overflow and truncate
            bool overflow = (end >= MSG_BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (overflow) {
                end = MSG_BUFFER_SIZE - 1;
            }

            // Carriage return is optional
            if (end > 0 && buffer[end-1] == '\r') {
                --end;
            }

            // Terminate string, deliver, and reset
            buffer[end] = '\0';
            handle_message(buffer, end, overflow);
            end = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add character to buffer if there is sufficient storage
            if (end < MSG_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                buffer[end] = c;
                ++end;
            }
        }
    }

    // Small delay to avoid busy looping
    delay(100);
}
```

Then your loop can be simply:

```
void loop()
{
    process_input();
}
```

That provides some basic scaffolding around line-based input. It provides a generous buffer size of 1000 characters (including NUL-terminator), and handles over-sized messages by discarding extra characters and setting a flag. The `handle_message` function then only needs to worry about whole messages, and you can make that as simple or complex as you desire.

### Sequencing

From here, you may wish to add logic that ensures things happen in order. Now, I don't have this hardware to test, but going by the SIM900 AT command reference [here](https://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf), it appears that each of your commands should expect `OK` as the response.

Furthermore, that document also describes the exact response format (in section 1.4 AT Command Syntax):

> Commands are usually followed by a response that includes `<CR><LF><response><CR><LF>`

So, you should expect that every time you issue an AT command that has a documented response, you should expect a blank line, followed by that response on the next line. It's up to you whether to enforce this, or whether you want to be slightly more flexible and simply ignore blank lines.

Since you need to issue a bunch of AT commands to get set up, a simple way of doing that without using delay hacks is to put your program into a limited set of "modes". You are either in the startup sequence, or you're ready to receive SMS. Issuing commands one at a time also avoids potentially overflowing the module's internal buffer.

Here, I've defined a basic set of modes and array of AT commands, which will be run in sequence at startup. The next command is not issued until the previous one got an "OK" as per the specification:

```
enum Mode {
    MODE_STARTUP_COMMAND,        // Issue next startup command
    MODE_STARTUP_EXPECT_EMPTY,   // Expect blank line followed by OK
    MODE_STARTUP_EXPECT_OK,      // Expect OK
    MODE_STARTUP_ERROR,          // Startup sequence failed
    MODE_READY,                  // Ready to receive SMS
};
Mode mode = MODE_STARTUP_COMMAND;

const char* startup_commands[] = {
    "AT+CMGF=1\r",
    "AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r",
    NULL,                        // NULL ends the command sequence
};
const char** startup_next_command = startup_commands;

void setup()
{
    SIM900.begin(19200);
    Serial.begin(19200);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Now you can add the required state handling to your loop and message-handler, ensuring that things happen in the expected order:

```
void handle_message(const char* message, int length, bool overflow)
{
    if (mode == MODE_STARTUP_EXPECT_EMPTY) {
        if (length == 0) {
            mode = MODE_STARTUP_EXPECT_OK;
        } else {
            mode = MODE_STARTUP_ERROR;
        }
    }
    else if (mode == MODE_STARTUP_EXPECT_OK) {
        if (0 == strcmp(message, "OK")) {
            ++startup_next_command;
            mode = MODE_STARTUP_COMMAND;
        } else {
            mode = MODE_STARTUP_ERROR;
        }
    }
    else if (mode == MODE_READY)
    {
        // You probably received a SMS, and can handle it here. Add extra logic
        // as befits your needs.
    }
}
```

Finally, to actually run the startup sequence, extend the `loop` function as follows:

```
void loop()
{
    // Send next command in startup sequence
    if (mode == MODE_STARTUP_COMMAND) {
        if (*startup_next_command != NULL) {
            SIM900.send(*startup_next_command);
            mode = MODE_STARTUP_EXPECT_EMPTY;
        } else {
            mode = MODE_READY;
        }
    }

    // Input processing
    process_input();
}
```

### Demo

An example of this sequencing in action is here: https://godbolt.org/z/heM5K87eM

When developing software for an embedded device, it can be helpful to make a test-bed like this to check the basics of your code. That's especially useful if you don't have easy access to (or simply don't use) other techniques such as logging messages via the serial port.

There's nothing fancy about what I did in the demo. It doesn't need to be. It just needs to be functional.

### Notes

Using the above as a basic template, you should be in a reasonable position to perform error recovery if necessary, by adding extra states. For instance, if one of the AT commands returns an error, then right now your device is totally hosed until you reboot it. Instead, you might want to jump into a state that waits for some amount of time and then reinitializes the startup sequence.